# postgres createuser with password from terminal

Tags: postgresql, vagrant

I'm using vagrant to setup a new Ubuntu machine. With provisioning I'm in the need to create a new postgres user. Currently I'm using:

```
sudo su postgres
createuser -P myuser
```

Unfortunately provisioning fails because a prompt needs to be filled with password (`-P` flag).

Is there a way to pass the password to `createuser` like `createuser myuser --password test` or `echo test | createuser -P myuser`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
sudo -u postgres
psql -c "create role NewRole with login password 'secret';"
```

Comment: thanks! my problem is the db does not exist yet. is it possible to create the db and in this step also the user and password like `createdb -E 'utf-8' -l en_US.utf8 -O testDB -T template0 AND create role NewRole with login password 'secret `

Comment: Sure?  Just run `createdb` before calling `psql` to create a role.

Comment: What privileges does this assign to the user?